# Wordpress loop count

Tags: wordpress, loops, counter

I have created a simple Wordpress loop already but now it should loop a little differently and i dont know how to start or even where to start. I have inside DIV class="item-row-wrap" my loop it loops through DIV class="vinyl-wrap" normally.

My problem: i would like it to loop three times and then to create a new DIV class="item-row-wrap" and start again looping DIV class="vinyl-wrap" three times...and go on and on

```
Here is the code:
<code>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if(get_field('artist-repeater')): while(has_sub_field('artist-repeater')): ?>

<div class="item-row-wrap"> <!--START of item-row-wrap-->

    <div class="vinyl-wrap"> <!--START of vinyl-wrap-->
        <?php if(get_sub_field('play-repeater-songlink')): ?>
            <a class="play" href='<?php the_sub_field('play-repeater-songlink'); ?>' target="_blank"></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if(get_sub_field('moreinfo-repeater-song')): ?>
            <a class="more-info" href='<?php the_sub_field('moreinfo-repeater-song'); ?>' target="_blank"></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="vinyl-cover">
            <div class="vinyl-cover-plastik"></div>
             <?php if(get_sub_field('album-repeater-image')): ?>
             <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_sub_field('album-repeater-image'), 'thumbnail'); ?>
             <img class="album-cover-art" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php get_the_title(get_field('album-repeater-image')) ?>" />
             <?php endif; ?>
        </div> <!--End of vinyl-cover-->
        <div class="likeit">
            <?php if(function_exists(getILikeThis)) getILikeThis('get'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="artist-name-wrap">
            <div class="artist-wrap-left"></div>
            <div class="artist-wrap-mid">
                <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="artist-wrap-right"></div>
        </div> <!--End of artist-name-wrap-->
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <div class="song-name-wrap">
            <div class="song-wrap-left"></div>
            <div class="song-wrap-mid">
                <?php if(get_sub_field('song-repeater-name')): ?>
                    <p><?php the_sub_field('song-repeater-name'); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="song-wrap-right"></div>
        </div> <!--end of song-name-wrap-->


    </div> <!--END OF VINYL-WRAP-->


        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        Yht&auml;&auml;n artikkelia ei ole viel&auml; julkaistu.
    <?php endif; ?>

</div> <!--END OF ITEM-ROW-WRAP-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `$i` var before the loop.
Up the value just before the loops closes: `$i++`
Set a Modulo check around the `<div class="item-row-wrap">` (and the closing `</div>`)

[Modulo tutorial](http://www.learnphpin24hours.org/2010/07/14/php-modulo-tutorial/)

Not a complete answer but enough to get you started.

**example**
The example below shows how you should do this

```
<?php
$i = 0;
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
if(get_field('artist-repeater')): while(has_sub_field('artist-repeater')):

    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
        echo '<div class="item-row-wrap"> <!--START of item-row-wrap-->';
    }
    $i++; // up the numer of looped
?>
DO your magic
<?php
    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
        echo '</div> <!--END OF ITEM-ROW-WRAP-->';
    }


endwhile; //end have_posts()
endif;
```

Comment: how do i need to wrap the module? that it would work. i found a tutorial for using modulus operator:

[Tutorial](http://www.devchunks.com/web-development/using-the-php-modulus-operator/)

Comment: The tutorial you give does exactly what you want, it does it by 3. `if ($i % 3 == 0){/*do your magic*/}`

Comment: Sorry to ask but could you make me an example i really do not know how to start here :/

Comment: Now it is working but there is an endless loop and only the first post is shown endlessly. it is really close now :)

Comment: I think it is now working i played around a little bit whit the $i == number: :) Thanks a lot Janw :) i really appreciate it

Comment: if my answer is correct, accept is. That's how Stackoverflow works

Comment: I did modify your code now it is working and i will accept it now. Thanks again :)